# How to propagate gradient into a variable after assign operation?

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation

Long story short. Next peace of code describes desired behaviour i.e. variable value is modified by the optimizer

```
  x = tf.Variable(5.0)
  # x = x.assign(tf.constant(5.0))
  opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001, momentum=0.9)
  train_op = opt.minimize(x)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    sess.run(train_op)
    print(x.eval())            # => 4.9999 - Desired result
```

While assigning the value to a variable on the go is considered not gradient worthy operation:

```
  x = tf.Variable(5.0)
  x_ = x.assign(tf.constant(5.0))
  opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001, momentum=0.9)        
  train_op = opt.minimize(x_)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    sess.run(train_op)        # => ERROR: No gradients provided for any variable
    print(x.eval())
```

Is there a way to set the variable to a certain value and yet get its value modified by the gradient as a result of train operation?

Edit: code fix

Comment: You should minimize `x`, not `x_`. The `x_` is an assign operation that can be called in a separate `sess.run` call to modify the value

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov the goal is to minize x_ which represents not only assignment but a whole model. Say `x_ = large_network(x.assign(const))` and my goal is to optimize `loss(x_)` but catching the gradient in `x`

Comment: If you want to save gradient in `x` you can do something like `tf.assign(x, gradient)`. If you want to set `x` to certain value and then minimize it, you can run `tf.assign(x, somevalue)`, then run `tf.assign_add(x, gradient)`

Answer (score 0):

Dirty hack for this one:

```
  x = tf.Variable(99.0)
  const = tf.constant(5.0)
  x_ = x + tf.stop_gradient(-x) + const # ARGHH
  opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001, momentum=0.9)
  train = opt.minimize(x_)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(x_.eval())
    x_original = x.eval()
    sess.run(train)
    print(x.eval() - x_original + const.eval())
```